# linux + sed + delete everything after dot

Tags: text-processing

```
more /tmp/file

sar -p: Average:        all     21.48      0.00      6.95      2.15      0.00     69.41
```

how to remove everything after dot

as the following

```
sar -p: Average:        all     21      0      6      2      0     69
```

we try

```
sed 's/.*//' /tmp/file
```

but not help

Comment: Is the file space- or tab-delimited?

Comment: just remove the dot in numbers and everything after dot

Comment: The delimiter can be important when designing regular expressions, which is why I asked. Btw, you added the `perl` tag ... why?

Comment: The actual question seems to be _How do I adjust the precision of the output of the `sar` command?_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+/\1/g' /tmp/file
```

It looks specifically for more than one digit, followed by a period, followed by more digits, and replace it with the part before the period (the group enclosed in `( ... )`).

Comment: @terdon good point. Unfortunately, my (GNU) `sed` manpage doesn't even mention it, although it works :(.

Comment: Yeah, the newer versions do mention it. For the older ones, you have to check `info sed` instead. If it's any consolation, the only reason I know this is because someone made the same edit to one of my posts here some years ago :).

Comment: I see. Actually, it is a consolation ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I Tried with Below method  and worked fine

command

```
 sed "s/\.[0-9]\{2\}//g"  file
```

output

```
sar -p: Average:        all     21      0      6      2      0     69
```

Adding another method using python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'\.[0-9]{2}')
o=open('file','r')
for i in o:
    print re.sub(k,"",i)
```